# How to get Image Reference from own Table with FilesProcessor in TYPO3 for FluidStyledContent CE?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, fal, fluid-styled-content

I've made an own CE in TYPO3 7.6 with a Repeater Field. I'm able to save images everythings fine - but I can't get them in my Fluid Template? I asume I've to nest the DatabaseQueryProcessor and the FilesProcessor somehow? But I can't figure out how?

ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
    tx_repeater_cooperationsslider int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tx_repeater_cooperationsslider (
    uid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    pid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    parentid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    parenttable varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    sorting int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    t3ver_oid int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    t3ver_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    t3ver_wsid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    t3ver_label varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    t3ver_state tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    t3ver_stage int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    t3ver_count int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    t3ver_tstamp int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    t3ver_move_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    tstamp int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    crdate int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    cruser_id int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    deleted tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    hidden tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    starttime tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    endtime tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sys_language_uid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    l10n_parent int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    l10n_diffsource mediumblob,
    tx_repeater_image int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    tx_repeater_buttonlink tinytext,
    PRIMARY KEY (uid),
    KEY parent (pid),
    KEY t3ver_oid (t3ver_oid,t3ver_wsid),
    KEY language (l10n_parent,sys_language_uid)
);
```

Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
$tempColumns = array (
  'tx_repeater_cooperationsslider' => 
  array (
    'config' => 
    array (
      'type' => 'inline',
      'foreign_table' => 'tx_repeater_cooperationsslider',
      'foreign_field' => 'parentid',
      'foreign_table_field' => 'parenttable',
      'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting',
      'appearance' => 
      array (
        'enabledControls' => 
        array (
          'dragdrop' => '1',
        ),
        'collapseAll' => '1',
        'newRecordLinkTitle' => 'Neuen Förderer anlegen',
        'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
        'useSortable' => '1',
        'showSynchronizationLink' => '1',
        'showAllLocalizationLink' => '1',
      ),
      'minitems' => '1',
      'maxitems' => '3',
      'behaviour' => 
      array (
        'localizationMode' => 'select',
      ),
    ),
    'exclude' => '1',
    'label' => 'Förderer',
  ),
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content', $tempColumns);


$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['items'][] = array(
    'Kooperationen',
    'cooperationsslider',
);

$tempTypes = array (

  'cooperationsslider' => 
  array (
    'showitem' => '--palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
    header;Überschrift,bodytext;Teaser Text;;richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css],rte_enabled;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:rte_enabled_formlabel,rowDescription;Button Text,header_link;Button Link,subheader;Subheadline,tx_repeater_cooperationsslider,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.visibility;visibility,
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.extended',
  )
);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types'] += $tempTypes;
```

Configuration/TCA/tx_repeater_cooperationsslider.php

```
<?php
return array (
  'ctrl' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Meine Meldungen',
    'label' => 'tx_repeater_buttonlink',
    'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
    'crdate' => 'crdate',
    'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
    'dividers2tabs' => true,
    'versioningWS' => 2,
    'versioning_followPages' => true,
    'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
    'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
    'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
    'delete' => 'deleted',
    'enablecolumns' => 
    array (
      'disabled' => 'hidden',
      'starttime' => 'starttime',
      'endtime' => 'endtime',
    ),
    'searchFields' => 'tx_repeater_buttonlink',
    'dynamicConfigFile' => '',
    'hideTable' => true,
  ),
  'interface' => 
  array (
    'showRecordFieldList' => 'sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, tx_repeater_buttonlink, tx_repeater_image',
  ),
  'types' => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'showitem' => 'sys_language_uid;;;;1-1-1, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden;;1,tx_repeater_image, tx_repeater_buttonlink, --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, starttime, endtime',
    ),
  ),
  'palettes' => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'showitem' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'columns' => 
  array (
    'sys_language_uid' => 
    array (
      'exclude' => 1,
      'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'foreign_table' => 'sys_language',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY sys_language.title',
        'items' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            0 => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages',
            1 => 0,
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            0 => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.default_value',
            1 => 0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'l10n_parent' => 
    array (
      'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:>:0',
      'exclude' => 1,
      'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.l18n_parent',
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'items' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            0 => '',
            1 => 0,
          ),
        ),
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_repeater_cooperationsslider',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_repeater_cooperationsslider.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND tx_repeater_cooperationsslider.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)',
      ),
    ),
    'l10n_diffsource' => 
    array (
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'passthrough',
      ),
    ),
    't3ver_label' => 
    array (
      'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.versionLabel',
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 30,
        'max' => 255,
      ),
    ),
    'hidden' => 
    array (
      'exclude' => 1,
      'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.hidden',
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'check',
      ),
    ),
    'starttime' => 
    array (
      'exclude' => 1,
      'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
      'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.starttime',
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 13,
        'max' => 20,
        'eval' => 'datetime',
        'checkbox' => 0,
        'default' => 0,
        'range' => 
        array (
          'lower' => 1483398000,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'endtime' => 
    array (
      'exclude' => 1,
      'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
      'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.endtime',
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'input',
        'size' => 13,
        'max' => 20,
        'eval' => 'datetime',
        'checkbox' => 0,
        'default' => 0,
        'range' => 
        array (
          'lower' => 1483398000,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'parentid' => 
    array (
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'items' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            0 => '',
            1 => 0,
          ),
        ),
        'foreign_table' => 'tt_content',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tt_content.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND tt_content.sys_language_uid IN (-1,###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid###)',
      ),
    ),
    'parenttable' => 
    array (
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'passthrough',
      ),
    ),
    'sorting' => 
    array (
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'passthrough',
      ),
    ),
    'tx_repeater_buttonlink' => 
    array (
      'config' => 
      array (
        'type' => 'input',
        'wizards' => 
        array (
          '_PADDING' => '2',
          'link' => 
          array (
            'type' => 'popup',
            'title' => 'Link',
            'icon' => 'EXT:backend/Resources/Public/Images/FormFieldWizard/wizard_link.gif',
            'module' => 
            array (
              'name' => 'wizard_link',
              'urlParameters' => 
              array (
                'mode' => 'wizard',
              ),
            ),
            'JSopenParams' => 'height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
            'params' => 
            array (
              'blindLinkOptions' => 'file,mail',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        'size' => '40',
      ),
      'exclude' => '1',
      'label' => 'Link Meldung',
    ),

    'tx_repeater_image' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'Logo hochladen',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                'tx_repeater_image',
                array(
                    'appearance' => array(
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                    ),
                    'foreign_types' => array(
                        '0' => array(
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ),
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => array(
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ),
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => array(
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ),
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => array(
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ),
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => array(
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        ),
                        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => array(
                            'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                        )
                    ),
                    'maxitems' => 1
                ),
                $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
            ),
        ),

  ),
);
```

typoscript

```
tt_content {

cooperationsslider < lib.fluidContent
    cooperationsslider {
        templateName = CooperationsSlider
        dataProcessing {


            20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            20 {
                if.isTrue.field = tx_repeater_cooperationsslider
                table = tx_repeater_cooperationsslider
                pidInList.field = pid
                where = parentid=###uid### AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0 AND 1=1
                orderBy = sorting
                markers {
                    uid.field = uid
                }
                as = data_tx_repeater_cooperationsslider
            }
30 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            30 {
                 references {
                                table = tx_repeater_cooperationsslider
                                fieldName = tx_repeater_image
                 }
                 as = images
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply stack those dataProcessors inside another to achieve what you want like so:

```
tt_content{
    contentslider < lib.fluidContent
    contentslider{
        templateName = CooperationsSlider
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            10 {
                if.isTrue.field = tx_repeater_cooperationsslider
                table = tx_repeater_cooperationsslider
                pidInList.field = pid
                where = parentid=###uid### AND deleted=0 AND hidden=0 AND 1=1
                orderBy = sorting
                markers {
                    uid.field = uid
                }
                as = data_tx_repeater_cooperationsslider
                dataProcessing{
                    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                    10 {
                        references {
                            table = tx_repeater_cooperationsslider
                            fieldName = tx_repeater_image
                        }
                        as = images
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can access this in your template via:
`{data.data_tx_repeater_cooperationsslider.images}`